# Error during cleanup of component this._app.unregisterRootNav is not a function at NavControllerBase.destroy

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma-jasmine to test a page using  with 3 tabs.

When begin the 2nd test case, error appears.
If I write only 1 test case, there are no errors.

I followed this answer but it didn't help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45775194/11663388

Please help!

"@angular/core": "5.2.11",

"@ionic-native/core": "^4.12.2",

"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",

```
describe('Test1', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TabsPage],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(TabsPage),
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../../assets/i18n/', '.json'),
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: App, useClass: AppMock },
        { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock },
        { provide: Firebase, useClass: FirebaseMock },
        TranslateService,
        { provide: DataServiceProvider, useClass: DataServiceProviderMock },
        { provide: CommonProvider, useClass: CommonProviderMock },
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavMock },
        { provide: RestProvider, useClass: RestProviderMock },
        { provide: TokenProvider, useClass: TokenProviderMock }
      ]
    })
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    // 
  });

  it('1.Normal case', done => {
    TokenProviderMock.authToken = '';

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TabsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    functionAsync().then(() => {
      expect(...).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });

  it('2.Error 400 handling', done => {
    TokenProviderMock.authToken = 'token';
    RestProviderMock.responceCode = 400;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TabsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    functionAsync().then(() => {
      expect(...).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
```

```
ERROR: [36m'Error during cleanup of component', Object{component: TabsPage{appCtrl: AppMock{}, platform: PlatformMock{resume: ...}, firebase: FirebaseMock{}, translate: TranslateService{store: ..., currentLoader: ..., compiler: ..., parser: ..., missingTranslationHandler: ..., useDefaultLang: ..., isolate: ..., pending: ..., _onTranslationChange: ..., _onLangChange: ..., _onDefaultLangChange: ..., _langs: ..., _translations: ..., _translationRequests: ...}, dataService: DataServiceProvider{toParentDataSource: ..., toChildDataSource: ..., toParentData$: ..., toChildData$: ...}, common: CommonProviderMock{}, navCtrl: NavMock{}, rest: RestProviderMock{}, token: TokenProviderMock{}, tab1Root: function WithdrawalPage(navCtrl,common,rest,token,firebase,platform,loadingCtrl){ ... }, tab2Root: function TransactionsPage(appCtrl,platform,common,token,dataService,rest,navCtrl){ ... }, tab3Root: function AccountPage(appCtrl,platform,translate,firebase,common,token,dataService){ ... }, resumeSub: Subscriber{closed: ..., _parent: ..., _parents: ..., _subscriptions: ..., syncErrorValue: ..., syncErrorThrown: ..., syncErrorThrowable: ..., isStopped: ..., destination: ...}, dataServiceSub: Subscriber{closed: ..., _parent: ..., _parents: ..., _subscriptions: ..., syncErrorValue: ..., syncErrorThrown: ..., syncErrorThrowable: ..., isStopped: ..., destination: ...}, firebaseSub: Subscriber{closed: ..., _parent: ..., _parents: ..., _subscriptions: ..., syncErrorValue: ..., syncErrorThrown: ..., syncErrorThrowable: ..., isStopped: ..., destination: ...}, retry: 0, tabs: Tabs{_config: ..., _elementRef: ..., _renderer: ..., _componentName: ..., _mode: ..., viewCtrl: ..., _app: ..., _plt: ..., _linker: ..., _ids: ..., _tabs: ..., _selectHistory: ..., _onDestroy: ..., ionChange: ..., parent: ..., id: ..., _sbPadding: ..., tabsHighlight: ..., _highlight: ..., _tabbar: ..., portal: ...}}, stacktrace: TypeError: this._app.unregisterRootNav is not a function
TypeError: this._app.unregisterRootNav is not a function
    at Tab.NavControllerBase.destroy (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:75720:23)
    at Tab.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:134069:14)
    at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:13044:18)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:13005:13)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:12988:29)
    at destroyView (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:14354:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:14505:13)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:14417:13)
    at destroyView (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:14353:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:15388:42)
    at Object.debugDestroyView [as destroyView] (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:14939:12)
    at ViewRef_.destroy (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:11958:18)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:11622:33)
    at ComponentFixture.destroy (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:29477:31)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:30082:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TestBed.resetTestingModule (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?a671f4c732cb1052c04ccc37ff945c825f9983dc:30080:30)
    at Function.TestBed.resetTestingModule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code

```
unregisterRootNav() {
  //do nothing
  return
}
```

to class AppMock